# User vandalizing their own post with 'delted question deleted question.. deleted question'

Tags: support

I'm from physics stackexchange. There's this user who's been going around self vandalizing his own posts and other posts. I would flag each, but it's gonna take a while with the quantity of posts he has effected right now, hope the moderators can have a look [(see here)](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/users/28922/deleted-account)

Comment: User got a lot of suspensions already. Hopefully the Engineering SE mods will soon take care.

Comment: Did he/she actually write "delted"?

Comment: That account is now deleted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We are aware, thank you.

The user has been temporarily suspended and the relevant question has been locked in the hopes the situation will soon blow over.

Once again, thank you for the heads up.